# Why is my output just a blank white image? [Python PIL]

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am getting a blank and white image instead of the desired output, help?

```py
from PIL import Image
def draw_nested_rectangles():
    height = int(input('Please enter the overall height: '))
    width = int(input('Please enter the overall width: '))
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB',size,'white')
    firstRec(width,height)
    secondRec(width,height)
    thirdRec(width,height)
    fourthRec(width,height)
    pic.show()
def firstRec(width,height):
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB', size, 'white')
    blueProgression = 0
    for x in range(width,width):
        color = (0,0,blueProgression)
        for y in range(height,height):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)
        blueProgression += 5
def secondRec(width,height):
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB', size, 'white')
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.15),int(width*0.85)):
        color = (0,greenProgression,0)
        for y in range(int(height*0.15),int(height*0.85)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)
        greenProgression -= 5
def thirdRec(width,height):
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB', size, 'white')
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.30),int(width*0.70)):
        color = (255,0,0)
        for y in range(int(height*0.30),int(height*0.70)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)
def fourthRec(width,height):
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB', size, 'white')
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.45),int(width*0.55)):
        color = (255,255,255)
        for y in range(int(height*0.45),int(height*0.55)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)
```

I want my output to be four nested triangles the first one being 100% of the width and height (starting off black on the right side and gradually increasing to blue) and the second being nested in the first being 70% of the original width and height (starting off black on the left side and gradually increasing to green) and the third being nested in and being 40% the original (pure red) while the last is nested in and being 10% (pure white)

Comment: Your code creates five entirely separate images.  The ones that you actually draw any pixels into are discarded without ever being displayed.  You probably want to pass `pic` as a parameter to your functions, so that you can draw into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY:-**

```
from PIL import Image



def draw_nested_rectangles():
    global pic
    height = int(input('Please enter the overall height: '))
    width = int(input('Please enter the overall width: '))
    size = (width,height)
    pic = Image.new('RGB', size, 'white')
    firstRec(width, height)
    secondRec(width, height)
    thirdRec(width, height)
    fourthRec(width, height)
    pic.show()

def firstRec(width,height):
    global pic
    size = (width,height)
    blueProgression = 0
    for x in range(width,width):
        color = (0,0,blueProgression)
        for y in range(height,height):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)
        blueProgression += 5

def secondRec(width,height):
    global pic
    size = (width,height)
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.15),int(width*0.85)):
        color = (0,greenProgression,0)
        for y in range(int(height*0.15),int(height*0.85)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y), color)
        greenProgression -= 5

def thirdRec(width,height):
    global pic
    size = (width,height)
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.30),int(width*0.70)):
        color = (255,0,0)
        for y in range(int(height*0.30),int(height*0.70)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)

def fourthRec(width,height):
    global pic
    size = (width,height)
    greenProgression = 255
    for x in range(int(width*0.45),int(width*0.55)):
        color = (255,255,255)
        for y in range(int(height*0.45),int(height*0.55)):
            pic.putpixel((x,y),color)


pic = 0
draw_nested_rectangles()
```

**REASON FOR UNDESIRABLE OUTPUT:-**

The reason why you were getting a blank image, rather then the one you expected is because, you were creating a separate `pic` image object inside each function, due to which all the function were working on separate image objects rather then a single one.

**FIX:-**

In order to get the desired output, you have to define the `pic` variable as global, inside each function that want to use it, by using the syntax `global pic`

**SAMPLE INPUT:-**

```
Please enter the overall height: 500
Please enter the overall width: 500
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:-**

[image]